# Where can I buy a katana?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

Where can I buy a katana in Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition?

I know I could buy on in Candlekeep, but I already left it and cannot return (the guard says I need to give him some book of 'great value' that I don't have).

It sucks having 3 proficiency in katanas and not having one to pew pew.

Answer (score 5):

From memory, I think you can buy them (or at least, buy one) from a shop in Baldur's Gate itself. There's a Katana +1 at the bottom of the Cloakwood Mines.

EDIT: 
While I don't have the game installed any longer (or saves near the relevant locations) I can use to confirm, these two threads ([here](http://forum.baldursgate.com/discussion/11621/katanas-outside-of-candlekeep) and [here](http://forum.baldursgate.com/discussion/7909/katana-vendor-where-art-thou)) seem to confirm my recollections.